# odometer format not work

Tags: javascript, css

I use [odometer](https://github.com/HubSpot/odometer) and I want to show float number with its decimal so, I added this code to my js

```js
window.odometerOptions = {
  auto: false, // Don't automatically initialize everything with class 'odometer'
  selector: '.my-numbers', // Change the selector used to automatically find things to be animated
  format: '(,ddd).dd', // Change how digit groups are formatted, and how many digits are shown after the decimal point
  duration: 3000, // Change how long the javascript expects the CSS animation to take
  theme: 'car', // Specify the theme (if you have more than one theme css file on the page)
  animation: 'count' // Count is a simpler animation method which just increments the value,
                     // use it when you're looking for something more subtle.
};
```

But still got the same problem that the format of showing number : 230.00 -> 230
Please let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is one (working) patched version of [odometer](http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/) on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fedek6/9c1ck8xd/1/), you can see in resources, the script is [here](http://realhe.ro/cursor-meter/js/odometer-patched.js) and minified below:

```js
(function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F=[].slice;q='<span class="odometer-value"></span>',n='<span class="odometer-ribbon"><span class="odometer-ribbon-inner">'+q+"</span></span>",d='<span class="odometer-digit"><span class="odometer-digit-spacer">8</span><span class="odometer-digit-inner">'+n+"</span></span>",g='<span class="odometer-formatting-mark"></span>',c="(,ddd).dd",h=/^\(?([^)]*)\)?(?:(.)(d+))?$/,i=30,f=2e3,a=20,j=2,e=.5,k=1e3/i,b=1e3/a,o="transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd",x=document.createElement("div").style,p=null!=x.transition||null!=x.webkitTransition||null!=x.mozTransition||null!=x.oTransition,v=window.requestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame,l=window.MutationObserver||window.WebKitMutationObserver||window.MozMutationObserver,s=function(a){var b;return b=document.createElement("div"),b.innerHTML=a,b.children[0]},u=function(a,b){return a.className=a.className.replace(new RegExp("(^| )"+b.split(" ").join("|")+"( |$)","gi")," ")},r=function(a,b){return u(a,b),a.className+=" "+b},y=function(a,b){var c;if(null!=document.createEvent)return c=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"),c.initEvent(b,!0,!0),a.dispatchEvent(c)},t=function(){var a,b;return null!=(a=null!=(b=window.performance)&&"function"==typeof b.now?b.now():void 0)?a:+new Date},w=function(a,b){return null==b&&(b=0),b?(a*=Math.pow(10,b),a+=.5,a=Math.floor(a),a/=Math.pow(10,b)):Math.round(a)},z=function(a){return a<0?Math.ceil(a):Math.floor(a)},B=!1,(A=function(){var a,b,c,d,e;if(!B&&null!=window.jQuery){for(B=!0,d=["html","text"],e=[],b=0,c=d.length;b<c;b++)a=d[b],e.push(function(a){var b;return b=window.jQuery.fn[a],window.jQuery.fn[a]=function(a){var c;return null==a||null==(null!=(c=this[0])?c.odometer:void 0)?b.apply(this,arguments):this[0].odometer.update(a)}}(a));return e}})(),setTimeout(A,0),m=function(){function a(b){var d,e,g,h,i,l,m,n,o,p=this;if(this.options=b,this.el=this.options.el,null!=this.el.odometer)return this.el.odometer;this.el.odometer=this,m=a.options;for(d in m)g=m[d],null==this.options[d]&&(this.options[d]=g);null==(h=this.options).duration&&(h.duration=f),this.MAX_VALUES=this.options.duration/k/j|0,this.resetFormat(),this.value=this.cleanValue(null!=(n=this.options.value)?n:""),this.renderInside(),this.render();try{for(o=["innerHTML","innerText","textContent"],i=0,l=o.length;i<l;i++)e=o[i],null!=this.el[e]&&function(a){Object.defineProperty(p.el,a,{get:function(){var b;return"innerHTML"===a?p.inside.outerHTML:null!=(b=p.inside.innerText)?b:p.inside.textContent},set:function(a){return p.update(a)}})}(e)}catch(a){a,this.watchForMutations()}}return a.prototype.renderInside=function(){return this.inside=document.createElement("div"),this.inside.className="odometer-inside",this.el.innerHTML="",this.el.appendChild(this.inside)},a.prototype.watchForMutations=function(){var b=this;if(null!=l)try{return null==this.observer&&(this.observer=new l(function(a){var c;return c=b.el.innerText,b.renderInside(),b.render(b.value),b.update(c)})),this.watchMutations=!0,this.startWatchingMutations()}catch(b){b}},a.prototype.startWatchingMutations=function(){if(this.watchMutations)return this.observer.observe(this.el,{childList:!0})},a.prototype.stopWatchingMutations=function(){var a;return null!=(a=this.observer)?a.disconnect():void 0},a.prototype.cleanValue=function(a){var b;return"string"==typeof a&&(a=a.replace(null!=(b=this.format.radix)?b:".","<radix>"),a=a.replace(/[.,]/g,""),a=a.replace("<radix>","."),a=parseFloat(a,10)||0),w(a,this.format.precision)},a.prototype.bindTransitionEnd=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g=this;if(!this.transitionEndBound){for(this.transitionEndBound=!0,b=!1,e=o.split(" "),f=[],c=0,d=e.length;c<d;c++)a=e[c],f.push(this.el.addEventListener(a,function(){return!!b||(b=!0,setTimeout(function(){return g.render(),b=!1,y(g.el,"odometerdone")},0),!0)},!1));return f}},a.prototype.resetFormat=function(){var a,b,d,e,f,g,i,j;if(a=null!=(i=this.options.format)?i:c,a||(a="d"),!(d=h.exec(a)))throw new Error("Odometer: Unparsable digit format");return j=d.slice(1,4),g=j[0],f=j[1],b=j[2],e=(null!=b?b.length:void 0)||0,this.format={repeating:g,radix:f,precision:e}},a.prototype.render=function(a){var b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m;for(null==a&&(a=this.value),this.stopWatchingMutations(),this.resetFormat(),this.inside.innerHTML="",g=this.options.theme,b=this.el.className.split(" "),f=[],i=0,k=b.length;i<k;i++)c=b[i],c.length&&((e=/^odometer-theme-(.+)$/.exec(c))?g=e[1]:/^odometer(-|$)/.test(c)||f.push(c));for(f.push("odometer"),p||f.push("odometer-no-transitions"),g?f.push("odometer-theme-"+g):f.push("odometer-auto-theme"),this.el.className=f.join(" "),this.ribbons={},this.digits=[],h=!this.format.precision,m=a.toFixed(this.format.precision).split("").reverse(),j=0,l=m.length;j<l;j++)d=m[j],"."===d&&(h=!0),this.addDigit(d,h);return this.startWatchingMutations()},a.prototype.update=function(a){var b,c=this;if(a=this.cleanValue(a),b=a-this.value)return u(this.el,"odometer-animating-up odometer-animating-down odometer-animating"),b>0?r(this.el,"odometer-animating-up"):r(this.el,"odometer-animating-down"),this.stopWatchingMutations(),this.animate(a),this.startWatchingMutations(),setTimeout(function(){return c.el.offsetHeight,r(c.el,"odometer-animating")},0),this.value=a},a.prototype.renderDigit=function(){return s(d)},a.prototype.insertDigit=function(a,b){return null!=b?this.inside.insertBefore(a,b):this.inside.children.length?this.inside.insertBefore(a,this.inside.children[0]):this.inside.appendChild(a)},a.prototype.addSpacer=function(a,b,c){var d;return d=s(g),d.innerHTML=a,c&&r(d,c),this.insertDigit(d,b)},a.prototype.addDigit=function(a,b){var c,d,e,f;if(null==b&&(b=!0),"-"===a)return this.addSpacer(a,null,"odometer-negation-mark");if("."===a)return this.addSpacer(null!=(f=this.format.radix)?f:".",null,"odometer-radix-mark");if(b)for(e=!1;;){if(!this.format.repeating.length){if(e)throw new Error("Bad odometer format without digits");this.resetFormat(),e=!0}if(c=this.format.repeating[this.format.repeating.length-1],this.format.repeating=this.format.repeating.substring(0,this.format.repeating.length-1),"d"===c)break;this.addSpacer(c)}return d=this.renderDigit(),d.querySelector(".odometer-value").innerHTML=a,this.digits.push(d),this.insertDigit(d)},a.prototype.animate=function(a){return p&&"count"!==this.options.animation?this.animateSlide(a):this.animateCount(a)},a.prototype.animateCount=function(a){var c,d,e,f,g,h=this;if(d=+a-this.value)return f=e=t(),c=this.value,(g=function(){var i,j,k;return t()-f>h.options.duration?(h.value=a,h.render(),void y(h.el,"odometerdone")):(i=t()-e,i>b&&(e=t(),k=i/h.options.duration,j=d*k,c+=j,h.render(Math.round(c))),null!=v?v(g):setTimeout(g,b))})()},a.prototype.getDigitCount=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f;for(d=1<=arguments.length?F.call(arguments,0):[],a=e=0,f=d.length;e<f;a=++e)c=d[a],d[a]=Math.abs(c);return b=Math.max.apply(Math,d),Math.ceil(Math.log(b+1)/Math.log(10))},a.prototype.getFractionalDigitCount=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g;for(e=1<=arguments.length?F.call(arguments,0):[],b=/^\-?\d*\.(\d*?)$/,a=f=0,g=e.length;f<g;a=++f)d=e[a],e[a]=d.toFixed(this.format.precision),c=b.exec(e[a]),e[a]=null==c?0:c[1].length;return Math.max.apply(Math,e)},a.prototype.resetDigits=function(){return this.digits=[],this.ribbons=[],this.inside.innerHTML="",this.resetFormat()},a.prototype.animateSlide=function(a){var b,c,d,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,s,t,u,v,x,y,A,B,C,D,E,F;s=this.value,j=this.getFractionalDigitCount(s,a),j=this.getFractionalDigitCount(s,a);var G=(z(a)+"").length,H=(z(s)+"").length,I=Math.max(G,H);if(j&&(a*=Math.pow(10,j),s*=Math.pow(10,j)),d=a-s){for(this.bindTransitionEnd(),f=I+j,g=[],b=0,m=v=0;0<=f?v<f:v>f;m=0<=f?++v:--v){if(t=z(s/Math.pow(10,f-m-1)),i=z(a/Math.pow(10,f-m-1)),h=i-t,Math.abs(h)>this.MAX_VALUES){for(l=[],n=h/(this.MAX_VALUES+this.MAX_VALUES*b*e),c=t;h>0&&c<i||h<0&&c>i;)l.push(Math.round(c)),c+=n;l[l.length-1]!==i&&l.push(i),b++}else l=function(){F=[];for(var a=t;t<=i?a<=i:a>=i;t<=i?a++:a--)F.push(a);return F}.apply(this);for(m=x=0,A=l.length;x<A;m=++x)k=l[m],l[m]=Math.abs(k%10);g.push(l)}for(this.resetDigits(),E=g.reverse(),m=y=0,B=E.length;y<B;m=++y)for(l=E[m],this.digits[m]||this.addDigit(" ",m>=j),null==(u=this.ribbons)[m]&&(u[m]=this.digits[m].querySelector(".odometer-ribbon-inner")),this.ribbons[m].innerHTML="",d<0&&(l=l.reverse()),o=D=0,C=l.length;D<C;o=++D)k=l[o],q=document.createElement("div"),q.className="odometer-value",q.innerHTML=k,this.ribbons[m].appendChild(q),o===l.length-1&&r(q,"odometer-last-value"),0===o&&r(q,"odometer-first-value");return t<0&&this.addDigit("-"),p=this.inside.querySelector(".odometer-radix-mark"),null!=p&&p.parent.removeChild(p),j?this.addSpacer(this.format.radix,this.digits[j-1],"odometer-radix-mark"):void 0}},a}(),m.options=null!=(D=window.odometerOptions)?D:{},setTimeout(function(){var a,b,c,d,e;if(window.odometerOptions){d=window.odometerOptions,e=[];for(a in d)b=d[a],e.push(null!=(c=m.options)[a]?(c=m.options)[a]:c[a]=b);return e}},0),m.init=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f;if(null!=document.querySelectorAll){for(b=document.querySelectorAll(m.options.selector||".odometer"),f=[],c=0,d=b.length;c<d;c++)a=b[c],f.push(a.odometer=new m({el:a,value:null!=(e=a.innerText)?e:a.textContent}));return f}},null!=(null!=(E=document.documentElement)?E.doScroll:void 0)&&null!=document.createEventObject?(C=document.onreadystatechange,document.onreadystatechange=function(){return"complete"===document.readyState&&!1!==m.options.auto&&m.init(),null!=C?C.apply(this,arguments):void 0}):document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){if(!1!==m.options.auto)return m.init()},!1),window.Odometer=m}).call(this);
```

The other solution is to use 3 decimal places and hide last digit. That would mean:

> To animate from 00.00 to 56.20 using the workaround described above,
>   you would animate from 100.001 to 156.201 and then use the CSS to
>   hide the first and last digits.

More about it [here](https://github.com/HubSpot/odometer/issues/106#issuecomment-289820962).